# how do you install a zip (or tag.gz) file in an anaconda prompt with Python 2.7 (I want to install a version of PyQt4)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, conda, python-sip

I have downloaded Anaconda 64 bit with Python 2.7 on my compter which works with Windows.
I also downloaded PyQt4 version 4.11.4.
However, when I run my code, I have this :

RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v9.0 to v9.2 but the PyQt4.QtGui module requires API v11.3

I tried to update the sip module, but I can't go further than version 4.18 due (I think) to the version of Python I use. However, I really need to use Python 2.7 since the code that I'm trying to run is old and written in Python 2.

I found out that PyQt4 version 4.9.6 requires a API version 9.1, so it would be supported by the sip module I have.

My problem is that only found that version of PyQt4 in zip file or in tag.gz file and I only know how to install .whl file (with the "pip install" in the anaconda prompt).

I was wondering if someone could please explain me how to install a zip or tag.gz file or if there is a web site that I could use to transform the zip (or tag.gz file) into a .whl file.

Comment: Have you tried installing with conda `conda install -c free pyqt==4.11.4`?

Comment: No I haven't! I will go try that thank you!

Comment: Where did you get the zp file from?

Comment: from sourceforge :/, it's the inly website I found that had the version 9.6.4

Comment: sorry version 4.9.6**